# Site images and information moves when altering the size of the browser. How to stop this?

Tags: html

Hi I want the site tables to not move or the information in them when I make the browser window smaller.

How do I do  this?

Take google.com's homepage for instance the google logo does get pushed to the site to try and fit in the window when made smaller.

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width on your main container element, that is the narrowest you will accept the viewport becoming before a horizontal scrollbar is introduced.